# how can i change the loading style of kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using mvc kendo razor grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Aditro.Foundation.Dashboard.Web.Models.test>()
.Name("testGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Title).Width(120);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Body).Width(180);
    columns.Bound(c => c.LinkText).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(c => c.LinkUrl).Width(170);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(120);
})
.DataSource(source =>
{
    source.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("GetAnnouncements", "Settings")).Batch(false)
        .Create(read => read.Action("AnnouncementAddEdit", "Settings"))
        .Update(read => read.Action("AnnouncementAddEdit", "Settings"))
        .Destroy(read => read.Action("AnnouncementDelete", "Settings"))
        .Model(model => { model.Id("AnnouncementId"); model.Field(x => x.Genus_List_Action).Editable(true); model.Field(x => x.Genus_List_Select).Editable(false); model.Field(x => x.Created).Editable(false); });
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Pageable(pageable =>
{
    pageable.Enabled(true);
    pageable.PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 });
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.Selectable(action => action.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
.Sortable(sort => sort.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
.Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))

)
```

my doubt is..is there any way to change to loading image using the inbuilt functionality of kendo grid. Or else i have to change the kendo.web.js file for it.

Please suggest some nice opinions thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some of mvc components Kendo mvc components are very flexible to change. For this purpose you can change related css or JavaScript file or also modifying loading image manually to meet your needs.
Kendo APIs are written in simplest manner and only it's assemblies are closed. So you can easily change  interfaces and functionality.